# Cómo ver el histórico de "npm deprecate"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Luego de ejecutar algo así como:

```
npm deprecate "mini-tools"@"< 0.2.10" "dependencies are deprecated"
```

no sé dónde ver cuál es el histórico de ejecución de `npm deprecate` sobre ese módulo. Poniendo

```
npm view mini-tools
```

se ve mucha información, pero no esa.

¿Dónde lo puedo obtener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes ver la información de deprecación de un módulo usando

```
npm view <módulo> deprecated
```

El problema de esto es que sólo aplica a esta versión en particular que esté marcada como obsoleta por lo que si haces

```
npm view mini-tools deprecated
```

No te mostrará nada ya que estarías usando la última versión como referencia. La forma correcta sería

```
npm view mini-tools@"0.2.9" deprecated
// Una versión menos para que sea <0.2.10 por lo tanto obsoleta
// Asumiendo que la versión 0.2.9 exista
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que devuelve

[image: deprecate]

Te puedes ahorrar todo este trabajo si abres directamente el JSON del registro npm en el navegador

https://registry.npmjs.org/mini-tools

El cual te dará un JSON con toda la información de todas las versiones de ese módulo. Así sabrás cuales versiones están obsoletas y cuales no.